# Matplotlib plot does not show legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label, legend

I want to quickly plot a function varying one of its parameters and with a legend showing the value of this parameter:

```py
def supergaussian1d(x, x0, Imax, FWHM, n):
    return Imax * np.exp(-4 * np.log(2) * (np.sqrt((x + x0)**2) / FWHM) ** (2*n))

x = np.linspace(0, 15, num=100)
for m in range(2, 9):
    plt.plot(x, supergaussian1d(x, x0=-7, Imax=10, FWHM=5, n=m), label='{}'.format(m))
    plt.ylim((0, 12))
plt.show()
```

This is the output:

[image]

Why is the legend not displayed?

Also, does it make a difference whether or not `plt.show()` is indented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding `plt.legend()` before `plt.show()`?

Comment: I *just* tried that and it works. Stupid me... Thanks!

Comment: no problem! you can also specify location of the legend inside the `plt.legend()` using parameter loc.